# Perl WWW::Mechanize::Firefox screenshots don't include backgrounds

Tags: perl, firefox, screenshot, mechanize

I don't know if this is possible or not, since I only just started using and learning Perl today, but I installed the `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` module and made sure to install the `mozrepl` plugin in Firefox itself to see if I could take screen shots of websites.

The script works and saves png files of website screenshots as expected. However if the website uses background colours and background images they are not included in the screenshot.

Is there a way to include these things or do I have to accept that this is just how it works?

For reference this is my simple test script:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use Path::Class qw/file/;

if(@ARGV == 2) {
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
        launch => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe',
        tab => 'current',
        autoclose => 'close|q',
        mozrepl => 'mozrepl|m:s'
    );

    $mech->get($ARGV[0]);

    my $fh = file($ARGV[1])->open( '> :raw' );
    print $fh $mech->content_as_png();
};
```

Comment: I don't know if WWW::Mech::FF's author reads SO, but he's on PerlMonks daily (as Corion). This sounds like a bug in WWW::Mech::FF (or more likely mozrepl), so filling a ticket in WWW::Mech::FF's queue would be appropriate.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for your comment. I will try to file a ticket soon and see what comes of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like what happens when you *print* a webpage

By default, background colors/images aren't used.

Firefox has a setting to enable printing those

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. As an extra note I also had to use sleep(5); to give my browser some extra time to download all of the background images after the $mech->get($ARGV[0]); line.